# React Router - Routes in different components

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My app is something like below, I have a two components - `App` and `Home`
I can go from App to Home, but in the `Home` component there are two other routes - `Profile` and `Quotes`.

On clicking the links for profile and quotes, I don't get any exception, and neither does it load that component.

However if I move the routes to the `App` component, then it loads `profile` and `quotes` just fine.

What could be the issue here. Please guide.

The App component is below -

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

class App extends React.Component {
    state = { //...some vals }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Link to='/home'>Home</Link>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/home' component={Home}/>
            </Switch>   
          </div>    
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

The Home component is below -

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import Profile from './Profile';
import Quotes from './Quotes';

class Home extends React.Component {
    state = { //...some vals }

    render() {
        return (
          <Fragment>
            <Link to='/profile'>Profile</Link>
            <Link to='/quotes'>Quotes</Link>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/profile' component={Profile}/>
              <Route exact path='/quotes' component={Quotes}/>  
            </Switch>
          </Fragment>   
        )
    }
}

export default Home
```

And in the `index.js` as below -

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'


ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>,
     document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: You can check out the answer I posted. Added a codesandbox example to understand better.

Comment: If there is nothing else than *home* in *app* you don't need a `<switch>`. And instead of using two `<router>`, you can use multiple switches with `match.url`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49208310/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-switch-in-react-js

Answer (score 3):

When you use routes in a component, it needs to be wrapped with a `Router` component. `BrowserRouter` in your case.

So, when you add routes to `Home` component, you need to do the same there.

But there will be an issue with that. Both the Routers are independent of each other and have a different `history` object.

This not a fix, you shouldn't be doing this. This is just for you to understand better:

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Profile from "./Profile";
import Quotes from "./Quotes";

class Home extends React.Component {
  state = {}; //...some vals }

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Fragment>
          <Link to="/profile">Profile</Link>
          <Link to="/quotes">Quotes</Link>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
            <Route exact path="/quotes" component={Quotes} />
          </Switch>
        </Fragment>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Check out the `Home` component and console of the `Quotes` component for  the history object.

[image: Edit mystifying-bash-ll666]

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like :

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "../components/Home";
// import your other pages/components here

const renderRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            render={props => (
              <AppRoute Component={Home} props={props} />
            )}
          />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

const AppRoute = ({ Component, Layout, props }) => {
  if (Layout) {
    return (
      <Layout {...props}>
        <Component {...props} />
      </Layout>
    );
  }

  if (!Component) {
    return <Layout {...props} />;
  }

  return <Component {...props} />;
};

export default renderRoutes;
```

And in your App.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import RenderRoutes from './routes';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <RenderRoutes/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

What you are doing now is making routes on a global level and you can use {NavLink} or {Link} anywhere in your app, start making routes by 
`<Route exact path="/" render={props => (<AppRoute Component={Home} props={props} />)}/>`

Just import your component and put it in `Component={YourComponent}` and add the path whatever you want to call it like `path="/Home/Profiles"`

Checkout this starter-kit on [GitHub](https://github.com/mughalhere/react-starter-kit)

Answer (score -1):

Remove `exact` from home `<Route` in App file.

App.js

```
<Route path='/home' component={Home}/>
```

use `exact` only when there is no child route associated with it otherwise it will not route to children route.

Update Home.js

Add `/home` in Home.js `Route` and `Link`

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import Profile from './Profile';
import Quotes from './Quotes';

class Home extends React.Component {
    state = { //...some vals }
    render() {
        return (
          <Fragment>
            <Link to='/home/profile'>Profile</Link>
            <Link to='/home/quotes'>Quotes</Link>
            <Switch>
               <Route exact path='/home/profile' component={Profile}/>
               <Route exact path='/home/quotes' component={Quotes}/>  
            </Switch>
          </Fragment>   
    )
  }
}

export default Home
```

I hope this will solve your problem.